# ReactJS - Difference between generates a unique id via default props and state

Tags: reactjs

For some reason i need to generate some unique ID to use them as CSS ID Selectors in a ReactJs component , I've done two examples:

1) Defining a random value in default props, see Test with default props below

=>It doesn't work

2) Defining a random value in state see Test with state below

=>It works

**Can some one explain why when i  use default props i've got always the same value?**

***Codesanbox :***

[Codesanbox link with all code example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/falling-wave-u613u)

***Source code :***

```
function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <h1>Components with random default props</h1>
          <DymmyComponentProps />
          <br />
          <DymmyComponentProps />
          <br />
          <DymmyComponentProps />
          <br />
          <DymmyComponentProps />
          <h1>Components with random state</h1>
          <DymmyComponenState />
          <br />
          <DymmyComponenState />
          <br />
          <DymmyComponenState />
          <br />
          <DymmyComponenState />
        </div>
      );
    }
```

**Test with default props:**

```
  class DymmyComponentProps extends Component {
          static defaultProps = {
            id: `Unique id is: ${Math.random()
              .toString(36)
              .substring(7)}`
          };

          render() {
            const { id } = this.props;
            return <p id={id}>{id}</p>;
          }
        }
```

**Test with state : (it work)**

```
class DymmyComponenState extends Component {
  state = {
    id: `Unique id is: ${Math.random()
      .toString(36)
      .substring(7)}`
  };

  render() {
    const { id } = this.state;
    return <p id={id}>{id}</p>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can some one explain why when i use default props i've got always the same value?

As you can see, `defaultProps` is a static property

```
static defaultProps = { 
    ...
};
```

Wich means it doesn't change on every new class, it's the same for every class.

And if you think about it, if the value is different on every instance of the class, it wouldn't be considered default, and in your case, it shouldn't be.

Comment: Thank, am wondering when i use Default props in ReactJS, i do have also the same value ? `DymmyComponentProps.defaultProps = {
  id: `Unique id is: ${Math.random()
    .toString(36)
    .substring(7)}
}`;`

Comment: yes, it's the same thing. `Math.random()
              .toString(36)
              .substring(7)` will run only one time

Comment: I've using a default random value for the seek that i can reuse the component many times without the obligation of setting up a unique ID for CSS selector every time,as this component will hold a canvas animation. and , Also to prevent braking the app if the user forgets to define a unique ID manually when calling the same components many times. Wondering if there is a better idea to do it , thanks

Comment: @TahaAzzabi setting it in the state is fine I guess, but using `Math.random` is very bad, you should take a look at guid or uuid